# How to use AsyncTask while file uploading to a ftp server

Tags: android, ftp, android-asynctask, uploading

I use FTPClient for uploading a file (selected by user) to my FTPServer.
And that code for uploading is working. :)
But when I add the AsyncTask for an "Uploading..." dialog, which shows to the user that it is uploading.
It shows the uploading dialog in my app it's crashes then and the uploading dialog doesn't disappear....

Following Error from LogCat:

```
11-06 12:01:05.153: I/System.out(27121):    ARGUMENT :: /storage/sdcard0/data-app/Z29sb2NrZXJpbmRlcGVuZGVudHZlcnNpb24
11-06 12:01:05.188: D/dalvikvm(27121):      GC_CONCURRENT freed 107K, 9% free 12896K/14151K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 13ms
11-06 12:01:13.923: I/System.out(27121):    status :: 211-Status of 'ProFTPD'

11-06 12:01:13.923: I/System.out(27121):    Connected from 109.164.221.167 (109.164.221.167)

11-06 12:01:13.923: I/System.out(27121):    Logged in as ftp031220

11-06 12:01:13.923: I/System.out(27121):    TYPE: BINARY, STRUcture: File, Mode: Stream

11-06 12:01:13.923: I/System.out(27121):    No data connection

11-06 12:01:13.923: I/System.out(27121):    211 End of status

11-06 12:01:25.988: W/System.err(27121):    java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
11-06 12:01:25.988: W/System.err(27121):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
11-06 12:01:25.988: W/System.err(27121):    at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:107)
11-06 12:01:25.988: W/System.err(27121):    at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:114)
11-06 12:01:25.993: W/System.err(27121):    at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:913)
11-06 12:01:25.993: W/System.err(27121):    at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:931)
11-06 12:01:25.993: W/System.err(27121):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.upload.upload(upload.java:124)
11-06 12:01:25.993: W/System.err(27121):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.upload$DownloadFilesTask.doInBackground(upload.java:153)
11-06 12:01:25.993: W/System.err(27121):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.upload$DownloadFilesTask.doInBackground(upload.java:1)
11-06 12:01:25.993: W/System.err(27121):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
11-06 12:01:25.993: W/System.err(27121):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-06 12:01:25.993: W/System.err(27121):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-06 12:01:25.993: W/System.err(27121):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
11-06 12:01:25.993: W/System.err(27121):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
11-06 12:01:25.993: W/System.err(27121):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
11-06 12:01:25.993: W/System.err(27121):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

> ==== On Item Click... ====

```
     @Override
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  File file = new File(path.get(position));

  if (file.isDirectory())
  {
   if(file.canRead()){
    getDir(path.get(position));
   }else{
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
     .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
     .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "] folder can't be read!")
     .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show(); 
   } 
  }else {
      new DownloadFilesTask().execute(path.get(position), file.getName());   
    }
 }
```

> ==== AsyncTask ====

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
     ProgressDialog dialog;

     @Override
     protected void onPreExecute() {
         dialog = new ProgressDialog(upload.this);
         dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
         dialog.setTitle("Datei wird hochgeladen...");
         dialog.setMessage("Bitte warten...");
         dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
         dialog.show();
     }

     protected String doInBackground(String... args){
         System.out.println("ARGUMENT :: " + args[0]);
         upload(args[0], args[1]);
         return root;

     }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
         dialog.dismiss();
     }
 }
```

> ==== Upload Function ====

```
    public void upload(String upload, String datei)
{
    try {
        connectFTP("176.28.25.46");

    // Prepare file to be uploaded to FTP Server
    File file = new File(upload);
    FileInputStream ifile = new FileInputStream(file);

    // Upload file to FTP Server
    if(ftpClient.storeFile("/subdomains/giveyourapps/httpdocs/apps/"+datei, ifile)){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setTitle("Datei wurde hochgeladen!")
        .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show(); 
    } else {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setTitle("Fehler!")
        .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show(); 
    }
    ftpClient.disconnect();
}catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: what's in `upload.java` line 124 and line 153?

Comment: line 124: .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show(); 
line 153: upload(args[0], args[1]);

Answer (score 3):

You cannot show a dialog in your task. In fact, you cannot perform any UI changes outside of the main (UI) thread. See the [Processes and Threads reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads) for more.

In you `Asynctask`, you should use `publishProgress()` and `onProgressUpdate()` to perform UI updates.

Read the [AsyncTask reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot show dialog in upload(). The method is invoked from within doInBackground and that method is running in the background thread, not in the UI thread.

Check the AsyncTask documentation on explanation of which AsyncTask methods execute in which thread and what is allowed and disallowed in either thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
public class loadVideo extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    int progress = 0;
    long duration;
    Notification notification;
    NotificationManager notificationManager;
    int id = 10;
    long pk;
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Check upload Status in the Notification Bar", 1).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
        notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                "Uploading file", System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.flags = notification.flags
                | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
        notification.contentView = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext()
                .getPackageName(), R.layout.upload_progress_bar);
        notification.contentIntent = pendingIntent;
        notification.contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageView1,
                R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        notification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1,
                "Uploading...");
        // notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.progressBar1, 100,
        // progress[0], false);
        getApplicationContext();
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
        System.out.println("DOMAIN...+" + str_edt_domain_name
                + "DOMAINPASSWORD..." + str_edt_username + "PASSOWRD"
                + str_edt_password);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        int count = 0;
        FTPClient ObjFtpCon = new FTPClient();
        // Toast.makeText(con, "FTPasync doInBackground() is called"
        // ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("man 0");
                    // bar.setProgress(0);
                    // real_time.setText(0 + " secs");
                    // test_avg.setText(0+ " kbps");
                    // peak.setText(0+" kbps");
                }
            });
            // updateUI(pp, R.drawable.pause);
            // ObjFtpCon.connect("ftp.customhdclips.com");
            ObjFtpCon.connect("domainname");
            // updateUI(status, "Connecting");
            System.out.println("man connecting");

            // if (ObjFtpCon.login("fstech@customhdclips.com", "fstech123"))
            // {
            if (ObjFtpCon.login("username", "password")) {
                // updateUI(status, "Connected");
                System.out.println("man CONNECTED");

                // toast("Connected to FTP Server : ftp.customhdclips.com");
                ObjFtpCon.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!
                //ObjFtpCon.cwd("/");// to send the FTP CWD command to the
                                    // server, receive the reply, and return
                                    // the reply code.

                // ObjFtpCon.connect("ftp."+map.get("url").toString());
                // updateUI(status, "Connecting");
                //
                // ObjFtpCon.login(map.get("username").toString(),
                // map.get("password").toString());
                // ObjFtpCon.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                // ObjFtpCon.cwd("/var/www/html/BevdogAnd");

                ObjFtpCon.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

                final long started = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long sleepingTime = 0;
                // String sourceFileUri
                // =extStorageDirectory+"/zkfile"+filename;
                File file = new File(path);
                long fileSize = file.length();
                int sentBytes = 0;
                InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

                System.out.println("Start uploading second file");
                OutputStream outputStream = ObjFtpCon
                        .storeFileStream("Meera Nandan at 60th Filmfare Awards 2013 _99_.jpg");
                byte[] bytesIn = new byte[512];
                int read = 0;
                while ((read = inputStream.read(bytesIn)) != -1) {
                    //updateUI(status, "Uploading");
                    System.out.println("man Uploading");

                    outputStream.write(bytesIn, 0, read);
                    sentBytes += read;
                    final int progress = (int) ((sentBytes * 100) / fileSize);
                    final long speed = sentBytes;

                    duration = ((System.currentTimeMillis() - started) - sleepingTime) / 1000;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                        //  bar.setProgress(progress);
                            if (duration != 0) {
                                //   test_avg.setText((((speed /
                                // duration)*1000)*0.0078125) + " kbps");
  //                                    test_avg.setText((speed / duration) / 1024
//                                          + " kbps");
                            System.out.println("MAN spped"+(speed / duration) / 1024
                                        + " kbps"+"and "+progress);
                                if (pk <= (speed / duration) / 1024) {
                                    pk = (speed / duration) / 1024;
                                }
                                /*
                                 * if (pk <= ((speed /
                                 * duration)*1000)*0.0078125) { pk =
                                 * (long)(((speed /
                                 * duration)*1000)*0.0078125); }
                                 */
                                // peak.setText(pk + " kbps");

                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                inputStream.close();
                outputStream.close();

                boolean completed = ObjFtpCon.completePendingCommand();
//                  updateUI(status, "Completed");
                System.out.println("MAN completed");
                if (completed) {

                }

            }

            /*-------------------------------------------------------------*/
            /*
             * URL url = new URL(map.get("url").toString()); URLConnection
             * conexion = url.openConnection(); conexion.connect();
             * updateUI(status, "Connected");
             * 
             * final int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
             * InputStream input = new
             * BufferedInputStream(url.openStream()); OutputStream output =
             * new FileOutputStream(
             * Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator +
             * Info.getInfo(con).HTTP_DOWNLOAD_FILE_NAME); byte data[] = new
             * byte[1024]; long total = 0; final long started =
             * System.currentTimeMillis(); long sleepingTime= 0;
             * System.out.println("started time --"+started);
             * updateUI(status, "Downloading"); while ((count =
             * input.read(data)) != -1) { while (sleep) {
             * Thread.sleep(1000); sleepingTime +=1000; } total += count;
             * final int progress = (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile);
             * final long speed = total; duration =
             * ((System.currentTimeMillis() - started)-sleepingTime) / 1000;
             * runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { public void run() {
             * bar.setProgress(progress);
             */

            /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

            else {
                System.out.println("password entered is incorrect");
                // Toast.makeText(con,
                // "Username or/and password is incorrect",
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // toast(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        try {
            ObjFtpCon.logout();
            ObjFtpCon.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // toast(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    // @Override
    // protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    //
    // Intent intent = new Intent();
    // final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
    // getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
    // notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
    // "Uploading file", System.currentTimeMillis());
    // notification.flags = notification.flags
    // | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    // notification.contentView = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext()
    // .getPackageName(), R.layout.upload_progress_bar);
    // notification.contentIntent = pendingIntent;
    // notification.contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageView1,
    // R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    // notification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1,
    // "Uploading...");
    // notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.progressBar1, 100,
    // progress[0], false);
    // getApplicationContext();
    // notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext()
    // .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
    // }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        System.out.println("status_string.." + status_string);
        Notification notification = new Notification();
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                getApplicationContext(), 0, intent1, 0);
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher; // icon from resources
        CharSequence tickerText = "Video Uploaded Successfully"; // ticker-text
        CharSequence contentTitle = getResources().getString(
                R.string.app_name); // expanded message
        // title
        CharSequence contentText = ""; // expanded
        if (upload_result == true && status_string.equals("1")) {

            contentText = "Video Uploaded Successfully";
            // message
        } else {
            contentText = "Video Uploaded Failed";

        }
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis(); // notification time
        Context context = getApplicationContext(); // application
                                                        // Context
        notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText,
                pendingIntent);
        String notificationService = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(notificationService);
        notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
    }
}
```